# Fabricjs: How to change opacity when object is being resized or scaled?

Tags: fabricjs

I want to set opacity of object to 0.5 when it is being moved/resized/scaled/drag.

We do have event handlers for all of them but they will be fired only once when any of these will start. I want to make object opacity=1 when activity is done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that you can use mouse:up event for that. And when mouse:up event fires you set the opacity to 1.

```
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(){
    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    obj.set({
        opacity: 1
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zL8akmxr/) with an example with scaling.

Comment: Thanks for jsFiddle. Works perfect.
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p0gc1fbq/) is updated with scaling/moving/resizing.